# When to use ViewChild and NgModel, how are they different?

Tags: angular

I am getting a little confused about ViewChild and NgModel. Can anyone give me definitive answer of when to use Viewchild and ngModel? I understand both will point to a particular element and you can use those objects to get the current value of element.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**NgModel**

NgModel is a way of two way data binding and can be used within your template and controller and if the value is changed in one it will reflect withing the other. A very common use would be with an input box looking, which could look like so.

```
<div>
    <input class="input-box" ([NgModel])]="myValue">
</div>
```

Which would sit in the controller as.

```
public myValue: string = 'hello;'
```

If this was either by the user from within the input box the variable myValue would change reflectively. If in the template you change the value like so. `this.myValue = 'goodbye''` this would change within the text box.

[NgModel documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel)

**ViewChild**

The viewchild can get be used to get reference of template elements, so you can see all the associated attributes. A common example would be if there were to be a custom component in a template a ViewChild could be used to pull values out of that component when needed. Looking roughly like so.

```
<my-custom-component #reference></my-custom-component>
```

Then in your controller you could define.

```
@ViewChild('reference')public myComponent; // type being the class of the child / element.
```

This would then allow you to gain access to everything inside the child component. I think why you are drawing a comparison is that you could do this with an input box and extract its value.

[ViewChild documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild)

Both are very useful tools with different applications. For generic two way data binding stick with NgModel, for obtaining reference to template elements / components I would stick with ViewChild.

Answer (score 3):

`ngModel` is used for one or two way property binding. You are right that you can use it to get the current value of an element.

The `@ViewChild` decorator different in that it is used to get the first matching instance of a component or directive. While you could use it to get a value from that component, it is not limited to just that.

Answer (score 2):

NgModel is used for inputs and is used within forms whereas a Viewchild can be used to point to a component/directive you have on your page.

NgModel will give you values for a given form field

ViewChild will allow you to access all public properties (values) and methods of the component you are pointing too.